# Display data in a React component from an object where the keys are different but the values are the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data that is in JSON format where the keys are different, but the objects nested inside have a keys that are the same (in this case I want a `title` and a `description`).

How do I display this data in a React component?

I've seen that you can 'map' through items in an object similar to how you would in an array using `Object.keys(objectName).map()` however since the keys at the next level are all unique, I'm not sure how to go down to the next level to get to the data I need.

The JSON data I'm working with looks something like this:

```js
const data = {
  dataINeed: {
    firstObject: {
      id: 'one',
      title: 'First title',
      description: 'First description',
    },
    secondObject: {
      id: 'two',
      title: 'Second title',
      description: 'Second description',
    },
    thirdObject: {
      id: 'three',
      title: 'Third title',
      description: 'Third description',
    },
  },
};
```

And 'mapping' through the data in React looks something like this:

```
{Object.keys(data.dataINeed).map((data) => {
  return (
    <dl>
      <dt>{data.*.title}</dt>
      <dd>{data.*.description}</dd>
    </dl>
  );
})}
```

Which obviously doesn't work as I can't use a wildcard selector.

Any suggestions on how to get to that next level of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where the keys are different but the values are the same

Just use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) directly.

```
{
  Object.values(data.dataINeed).map((data) => (
    <dl key={data.id}>
      <dt>{data.title}</dt>
      <dd>{data.description}</dd>
    </dl>
  ))
}
```

**SAMPLE JS**

```js
 const a = {
  dataINeed: {
    firstObject: {
      id: 'one',
      title: 'First title',
      description: 'First description',
    },
    secondObject: {
      id: 'two',
      title: 'Second title',
      description: 'Second description',
    },
    thirdObject: {
      id: 'three',
      title: 'Third title',
      description: 'Third description',
    },
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(a.dataINeed))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your map function you are getting `key` in each map call (`firstObject`, `secondObject`, etc.), so you need to extract your item by that `key`.

```
{Object.keys(data.dataINeed).map(key => {
    const item = data.dataINeed[key];
    return (
      <dl>
        <dt>{item.title}</dt>
        <dd>{item.description}</dd>
      </dl>
    );
})}
```

Here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sky-tfrg7).

Answer (score 1):

You might find Object.entries more useful for this than Object.keys, just note that it's ES2017 so you'll need to use the correct transpiler preset. It will return an array for each entry containing the key at index 0 and the object itself at index 1.

So for example:

```
Object.entries(dataObject).map([key, value])
```

will give you

```
[
    ["firstObject": {...firstObject}],
    ["secondObject": {...secondObject}]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following snippet and refer [Template string is JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Basically, in your map, you are getting key and hence you need to access the value using that key.

```js
const data = {
  dataINeed: {
    firstObject: {
      id: 'one',
      title: 'First title',
      description: 'First description',
    },
    secondObject: {
      id: 'two',
      title: 'Second title',
      description: 'Second description',
    },
    thirdObject: {
      id: 'three',
      title: 'Third title',
      description: 'Third description',
    },
  },
};


const value = Object.keys(data.dataINeed).map((item) => {
  const myData = data.dataINeed[item];
  return (
    `<dl >
      <
      dt > {
        ${myData.title}
      } < /dt> <
      dd > {
        ${myData.description}
      } < /dd>
      </dl>`
  );
})

console.log(value)
```